# Desktop entries in LXDE - how to debug them?

Tags: desktop, lxde

I use Debian Jessie on my laptop. From time to time I have trouble with proper creating Desktop entries for LXDE. I mean files with `.desktop` extension than can be placed in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` or `~/.config/autostart/` or `/usr/share/applications/`.
When they crash nothing happens. What is the way to debug them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
desktop-file-validate /path/to/desktop/file
```